# Problems with Bluetooth discovery

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

So I need device A (client) to connect to device B (server) and I've gotten it to work, but not in all cases. Upon opening the app, I want to allow the device to be discovered

```
private void enableDiscoverability() {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new 
                      Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);

    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 
    3600);
            startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }
```

, and i set up a receiver to look for one specific device (just for now, I'm still learning how to use Bluetooth)

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            TextView output = findViewById(R.id.output);
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                // object and its info from the Intent.
                BluetoothDevice temp = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String deviceName = temp.getName();
                Log.i("Device ", deviceName + " was found");
                String deviceHardwareAddress = temp.getAddress();
                if (deviceHardwareAddress.equalsIgnoreCase("DC:F7:56:DD:73:8F")) {
                    device = temp;
                    startClient();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

So here is my problem. When device A is left on, it'll discover new devices for a little while, but it won't discover the new device B after a few minutes. Both devices should have a receiver and should be discoverable.

Is there a timeout when you're discovering devices? Would something happen to the receiver if it tried to connect but failed? I've tried to look it up, but I'm still new with Bluetooth so I wouldn't know where to begin. I'd be more than happy to post more code if need be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Every device has a discovery timeout. Best place to start is bluetooth.com, with huge amount of videos and documents. There is timeout for every activity in Bluetooth such as discovery, connection, data transmission etc.